# Recurrence function in React Native

Tags: react-native

I would like to add a recurrence function in my react native project, but `setTimeout` doesn't work. Can you tell me why? And how to fix it?

```
handleAppStateChange(appState) {
    if(appState === 'background') {
        let i = 0;
        function runAction() {
            i++;
            console.log('result'+i);
            setTimeout("runAction()",1000);
        }
        runAction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First argument of `setTimeout` is a function, so try to

```
setTimeout(runAction,1000);
```

Comment: Hmm. it's working but only when app back to "active". Why it doesn't work when app is in background? Thank you.

Comment: It could be related with mobile os optimization or something. It's just a guess, but maybe OS clears memory then application goes to background, because in browser it's work clearly

Comment: Try using Date objects instead of timeouts. Just a guess. Not sure if it will work for you but it does work when using dates for locally scheduled notifications.